# How to enable Windows machine dhcp without being an admin?

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp

I am trying to use my home network using Ethernet cable, but it's showing the error: **Your DHCP was disabled**. I don't have admin rights so: How to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account and enable DHCP

Answer (score 2):

Without admin access to the machine, you will be unable to change system settings through any legitimate means.

Ask someone who does have Admin access to enable it for you. You'll probably have to explain why.

Answer (score -1):

- You may want to check the network adapter settings manually to make sure it is set up properly to accept automatic configurations. If that is not the case, then this may be the reason why Internet and network may not work flawlessly.
- Fix DHCP issues using the network troubleshooting. Sometimes, DHCP may not be available even though the adapter is configured properly. This may happen after you close a virtual private network connection on your system for instance.

**Edit:** As it was mentioned, the first method can only be used with admin rights. If you encounter this issue a lot, try asking an admin to add the user to the Network Configuration Operators group or change the privileges for the existing user. If troubleshooting doesn't solve it, only admin can deal with the issue

Comment: Doing this requires admin privileges. OP stated they do not have an admin account.

Comment: @CConard96 I never had an issue accessing the adapter settings to be honest. Either way, if he cannot access it, method 2 (troubleshooting) could solve it.